# Custom theme doesn't load theme css file in Drupal 8

Tags: css, drupal, yaml, drupal-8, drupal-theming

I'm making a new theme but have problems loading the css. Though I think it is correct to the documentation of Drupal it doesn't work.

I created a folder in /themes/custom/noadin and added the info and libraries files

noadin.info.yml :

```
name: noadin
description: 'My new theme'
type: theme
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - noadin/global-styling
  - noadin/global-scripts
```

and created a noadin.libraries.yml :

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
       css/style.css: {}
global-scripts:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
```

The stylesheet is placed at /themes/custom/noadin/css

Can anyone tell me what it is that I am misunderstanding?

p.s. Drupal is taking the correct theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your info.yml and libraries.yml looking fine, I think may be becouse of caching it is not loading the css and js file try after clearing the cache. (login to your admin area configuration->Development->Performance->Clear all caches) Try after this

You can try look in to this working sample (http://wiki.workassis.com/drupal-8-custom-theme-from-scratch/) this helped me.

Comment: It'd be best if the accepted answer clarified specifically what is wrong because there are really two different answers here

Comment: After trying so many things, clearing the cache was the answer, I'm new to Drupal and didn't know how to do that in the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have unchecked the following option from -
Home > Administration > Configuration > Development

**Aggregate CSS files** -- Uncheck and Save Configuration

Answer (score 0):

@Koustav answer helped me a lot. I did changed the drupal/sites/default/files to proper owner since the "Bandwidth optimization menu was disabled and then went to

Home > Administration > Configuration > Development

and unchecked the Aggregate CSS files

Now it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but resolved by doing the below steps.

1. Goto **admin/config/development/performance**
2. uncheck the Aggregate CSS files
3. uncheck Aggregate JavaScript files

Thanks!!!!!!!